# Usage of the for_each_process macro in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to iterate over each process in the kernel and modify some parameters in `task_struct`. I think I can use the `for_each_process()` macro to do so.

However, to do it safely, I have to ensure that the process is not being executed currently and also after I get reference to its `task_struct`, I want to lock it down so that no one else accesses it while I am modifying it.

How can I accomplish these two goals?

Comment: okay, I think for_each_process() is protected with rcu lock. So at least it is guaranteed that someone else will not free up that memory while I am using it. Now the question remains about how to protect it while I am modifying it.

Comment: This site's audience is mostly users and administrators, not programmers, so I think your question will fare better on [so]. Do not repost there; I've asked a moderator to migrate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int flags;  
smp_wmb(); 
raw_spin_lock_irqsave(&task->pi_lock, flags);
do your stuff
raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore(&task->pi_lock, flags);
```

to lock the task you are currently processing.